# How can I change the Bluetooth Received files folder location from Home>Public to the customized folder location?

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Lubuntu 14.10 OS in my HP Pavilion dv6000 laptop.

My question is;

How can I change the Bluetooth Received files folder location from Home>Public to the customized folder location?

Answer (score 1):

Search for `Personal File Sharing Preferences`  from the Dash.

[image]

You'll get a menu of options and you can change the default folder `home` to any other folder to bluetoothed into.

you can also use the app named blueman

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

you can easily change the folder using its "Local Services" option

Comment: I am not using "UBUNTU" ; It is "LUBUNTU" ... The OS in the above shown picture is "UBUNTU" not "LUBUNTU" ... I am using "LUBUNTU 14.10" ... It is entirely different from Ubuntu ... I searched "Personal File Sharing Preferences" in the Run Command ... Unfortunately, there is no such an option to choose ... :(

Comment: I tried to install blueman; I get the following in terminal:

soorej@soorej-HP-Pavilion-dv6000-RZ901PA-ACJ:~$ sudo apt-get install blueman
[sudo] password for soorej: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
blueman is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 194 not upgraded.
soorej@soorej-HP-Pavilion-dv6000-RZ901PA-ACJ:~$ sudo blueman
sudo: blueman: command not found
soorej@soorej-HP-Pavilion-dv6000-RZ901PA-ACJ:~$


NB:- Please resolve this problem as soon as possible